# Why does Kotlin need function reference syntax?

Tags: kotlin

Kotlin docs stated that it supports [higher-order functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html). Why would the language even need a `::function` syntax when passing a top level function as an argument?

Given:

```
fun isOdd(x: Int) = x % 2 != 0
val numbers = listOf(1, 2, 3)
println(numbers.filter(::isOdd)) // here.
```

Why not just

```
fun isOdd(x: Int) = x % 2 != 0
val numbers = listOf(1, 2, 3)
println(numbers.filter(isOdd)) // simple and makes more sense
```

More on the [function reference syntax here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#function-references).

Comment: One case that comes to my mind is: when there's a property of a functional type, say `foo: (T) -> R`, without `::` it would be confusing/ambigous whether you want to use value of `foo` or make a callable reference of `foo`.

Comment: Adding to that: it also lets you have a function and a property with the same name in the same scope that you can refer to unambiguously, and it resembles Java's syntax for referencing methods.

Comment: @hotkey I'm a bit lost, if you have a property of `foo: (T) -> R`, would a call to `foo` will just be translated to `getFoo()` and return the function? Which essentially the same with `::foo`? Please excuse my ignorance...

Comment: @YudhistiraArya, `::foo` means a callable reference of that property: you can call it and get its value -- that is, the function that you normally get as `foo`.

Comment: @YudhistiraArya, here's what I'm talking about: [(demo)](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/kpteq5gg5q9b4shs4ek4dich33/bnef7upvvfbf5h88b4l4t456s7)

Comment: @hotkey thanks for the example!

Comment: @YudhistiraArya the answer you marked as Accepted is not correct at all and is a misunderstanding of this situation.  This will mislead others in the future.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Kotlin language design tries to avoid ambiguous situations where some absence of something could be both correct and incorrect syntax at the same time.  For example if you allowed the proposed syntax:

```
isOdd     // error, function invocation expected isOdd(...)
isOdd     // not error, you have a function reference
```

The `::` is a clear signal as to the intent.  Because of this, you get only an error in the `isOdd` case because you now have possibilities that do not overlap:

```
isOdd      // error, function invocation expected isOdd(...)
::isOdd    // function reference
isOdd()    // error, missing parameter x
isOdd(x)   // function call
```

This is why Kotlin avoids things that lead to ambiguous states.  Your eyes can also quickly pick up the problem, just as the IDE and static analysis can, just as the compiler does.  If you start allowing this looser syntax you will start running into compounded ambiguities such as when using as infix functions and so on.  Language design is more complicated than "oh, let's make them type less characters" because the complexity matrix is much larger than you imagine if you only look at one use case ignoring all the others.

Comment: The problem you describe is not solved by references since references themselves are callable: `val newIsOdd = ::isOdd` allows `newIsOdd()` and `newIsOdd`. I don't even see this as a problem personally. But now we have a much more confusing problem: there are two types of functions, both of which are callable, but they can only be passed around *sometimes*. Consistency would be clearer. Either the two kinds of functions should have discrete syntaxes (like java) or there should only be one kind (like python), not a half-assed inconsistent middle ground.

Answer (score 6):

Because Java (and, therefore, Kotlin) uses separate namespaces for fields and methods, you need `::` to avoid ambiguities. Example:

```
val isOdd : (Int) -> Boolean = { x -> x % 2 != 0 }
fun isOdd(x: Int): Boolean {
    return x % 2 != 0
}

val odds = listOf(1,2,3).filter(isOdd) // uses the val version
val otherOdds = listOf(1,2,3).filter(::isOdd) // uses the fun version
```

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  Namespaces is not in play here at all, and this is a complete misunderstanding of the issue and why the code above works in this case.  See answer below about why this answer is wrong and misleading.

Comment: I find this answer as enlightening as the other one. There is no single "because" here, many forces are pulling the syntax this way or that.