# Returning a Recursive Function from another Kotlin Function

Tags: kotlin

This is Kotlin equivalent of function taken from the Scala MOOC on Coursera. It returns a function that applies a given mapper(f) on a range(a..b)

```
fun sum(f: (Int) -> Int): (Int, Int) -> Int {
    fun sumF(a: Int, b: Int): Int =
            if (a > b) 0
            else f(a) + sumF(a + 1, b)
    return sumF
}
```

But IntelliJ shows these errors. How can I return the function from here.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a you define a named function (`fun foo(...)`), you cannot use its name as an expression.

Instead, you should make a [function reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#function-references) of it:

```
return ::sumF
```

See also: [Why does Kotlin need function reference syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43396499/why-does-kotlin-need-function-reference-syntax)

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `::` to express it as a function reference.

```
fun sum(f: (Int) -> Int): (Int, Int) -> Int {
    fun sumF(a: Int, b: Int): Int =
            if (a > b) 0
            else f(a) + sumF(a + 1, b)
    return ::sumF
}
```